# Bootstrap 4 horizontal list group flush

Tags: bootstrap-4

If 'list-group-flush' class is added to horizontal list group then last child(li) does not have border-bottom. Should not it be considered as bug of Bootstrap 4? In addition, there are some border-radius present that are also not expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal List Groups</h2>
 
  <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using the "list-group-flush" class?

Comment: To remove outer border entirely.

Comment: Then that's not the right approach, one way is need to define your own css styles to override the bootstrap one

Comment: i have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bootstrap error, Because of list-group-flush

list-group-flush to remove some borders and rounded corners to render list group items edge-to-edge in a parent container

You can add border to last by applying styles to the last child of list item

Answer (score 0):

this is what you get when you remove the "list-group-flush"

[image]

if you want to remove the border all together (as per your comment)

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none;">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none;">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none;">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" style="border: none;">Fourth item</li>
  </ul>
```

and in this case you get:

[image]